# Entity Framework database first "entity type has no key"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework database first and the `.edmx` model is perfectly updated from the database. Then I ran the custom tool.

When I retrieve data from the database using linq queries, I get an exception

> entity type has no key

for only two out of 4 entities of my model - the `student` and `SupervisorTitle1` entities.

And as I said, I can see the foreign key relations correctly updated in the model from the database.

Through my research I found advice like adding a `[key]` attribute, but in the case of database first it is not possible to change the code which is automatically generated by Entity Framework.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCrrv.png)

Comment: The table needs a Primary Key and the imported entity should show that. Verify step by step.

Comment: Can't you manage your entities using Properties window in edmx desginer?

Comment: You said, you ran custom tool. Which custom tool you ran? Anything changed from Model.tt file?